Nginx unable to find new certificate
I use Nginx in a Docker container on Alpine. Used Certbot to generate a new certificate named my.domain.com-0004.
Replacing the certificate with either mv or cp resulted in an SSL protocol error and in logs Nginx was unable to see the file:
2024/04/22 08:41:34 [error] 46#46: *109 cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live//fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling fopen(/etc/letsencrypt/live//fullchain.pem, r) error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file) while SSL handshaking, client: 34.32.209.4, server: 0.0.0.0:443

Replacing the previous certificate, everything started to work again. I've tried restarting  the container without success.

Show us your config.

Posted most of the config. Hope that's enough.

So I've found what was the issue. The live directory does not actually have files. These are softlinks/symlinks:
root@server:/data/certbot/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com# ls -l fullchain.pem 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 systemd-resolve systemd-journal 49 Apr 21 20:10 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/my.domain.com-0004/fullchain2.pem

And there was no -0004 directory in archive directory, because it was renamed to -0003. After moving the certificate from -0003 to -0004 in archive, the live certificate symlink was correct and the new certificate started to work as intended.

While this might have been briefly helped you, think why that happened. I wouldn't suggest this solution to anybody, since it's a dirty hack done without deep understanding of what happened and without identification and resolution of the original issue. What I know for certain is that the new directory -0004 should have been containing newly created certificates, that it wasn't means your certificates weren't updated; those copied from -0003 will expire soon. Better consider deep certificate check, read /var/log/letsencrypt logs, to identify and fix the real issue.

If you look at your error message, you'll see "/etc/letsencrypt/live//fullchain.pem" as the name of the file it's trying to load. Your certificate is at /etc/letsencrypt/live/$ssl_server_name/fullchain.pem according to your cert.conf file. Seems fairly obvious to me that the variable $ssl_server_name has not been set and so is returning an empty string... and so it can't find your certificate because there isn't one where it's looking.

Then why it works when I switch to the old certificate by just using mv and not changing anything in Nginx? I'd rather think it's some kind of access issue rather than this.

It specifically states in the error message no such file which sort of argues against it being an access issue - if it was a permissions issue you'd see access denied instead. And where exactly are you mving the old certificate to? If it's going to the path that nginx expects, rather than the place letsencrypt has left it, of course it will work.

I move the old certificate from my.domain.com directory to my.domain.com-old and move the new one from my.domain.com-0004 to my.domain.com. The new certificate does not work, throwing the error above, but if I revert that, everything works again.

Are you saying that you did not post the error message correctly? Because the error message specifically does not include my.domain.com. Twice.

Nope. I'm saying that this whole situation is highly confusing to me and I completely do not understand why I get this error by a simple switch in certificates. The paths are literally the same. Nginx is not touched at all. If I want to make it work again, I just switch back to the old cert. I completely do not understand this. Does Alpine have some weird file restrictions while using mv or copy? Does the newly generated cert have some additional restrictions from Certbot? The chmods are the same.

The only thing that possibly is an issue, if you discount what the error message is saying, is that what appears in Certbot's live directory is a softlink. It keeps the old certificate alongside the new one in a history directory, and changes the softlink to point to the new one. But if you've quoted the error message correctly, there's something else going on that you should track down... and although you've never stated so, I'm hoping that when you say you copied the certificate, you also copied the private key.

Thank you for the softlink tip. Can I verify this somehow? Yes, the whole directory has been copied with both mv and copy and failed both times. I'm really confused by this whole situation as as I recall, I have been doing this the same way few months ago without any issues.

Simplest way to check for softlinks is ls -la on the directory.

Yup. It was a symlink issue. Thanks for the hint!
